# Consulta entre tres tablas y sub-consulta SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql, subconsultas

Tengo dos tablas, una de compañías y otra de usuarios, la cual a través de una query, extraigo las compañías asociadas a un departamento en especifico:

```
SELECT t1.RUT,
       t1.Compañia,
       t1.Email,
       t1.Telefono,
       t2.Usuario_responsable,
       t2.Departamento
FROM Companias t1
    LEFT JOIN Empleados t2
        ON t2.Usuario_Id=t1.Id_usuario_responsable
WHERE t2.Departmento = 'Ventas'
```

El asunto es que tengo una tercera tabla, que es donde se guardan las actividades hechas para cada compañía, realizadas por el mismo usuario u otro perteneciente al departamento en especifico.

La tabla tiene una estructura similar a:

```
| Id | Compania | Id_usuario_creador | Fecha | Actividad | Descripcion |
|----|----------|--------------------|-------|-----------|-------------|
```

Aquí radica mi problema, y es que necesito extraer el mismo listado de todas las compañías asocias al departamento de ventas, **pero que ademas**, se agreguen de la tabla de actividades, la ultima actividad realizada para cada compañía. Trate realizando una sub-consulta, pero me arroja una infinidad de registros y ademas duplicados y no pillo como realizarla.

```
SELECT t1.RUT,
       t1.Compania,
       t1.Email,
       t1.Telefono,
       t2.Usuario_responsable,
       t2.Departamento,
        (SELECT top 1 t3.Fecha
         FROM Actividades t3
         WHERE t3.Compania = t1.Compania) as Fecha_creacion,
FROM Companias t1
    LEFT JOIN Empleados t2
        ON t2.Usuario_Id=t1.Id_usuario_responsable
    LEFT JOIN Actividades t3
        ON t3.Id_usuario_creador = t2.Usuario_Id
WHERE t2.Departmento = 'Ventas'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba quitando el join con la tabla Actividades y en la sub consulta agrega la condición `and t3.Id_usuario_creador = t2.Usuario_Id`

```
SELECT t1.RUT,
       t1.Compañia,
       t1.Email,
       t1.Telefono,
       t2.Usuario_responsable,
       t2.Departamento,
(SELECT top 1 t3.Fecha
         FROM Actividades t3
         WHERE t3.Compania = t1.Compania 
         and t3.Id_usuario_creador = t2.Usuario_Id) as Fecha_creacion
FROM Companias t1
    LEFT JOIN Empleados t2
        ON t2.Usuario_Id=t1.Id_usuario_responsable
WHERE t2.Departmento = 'Ventas'
```

Comment: Estimado, ocupe tu query, ahora si me entregaba la cantidad de registros correctos, pero para Fecha_creacion me entregaba solo valores NULL, probe quitar el AND del WHERE de la sub consulta y ahi si consegui valores.
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!